# I am not able analyze WhitespaceAnalyzer in schema.xml

Tags: solr

When I add analyzer in schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="nametext" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer"/>
</fieldType>
```

And reload the core in solr 5.0.0, I get following error:

```
testcore: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: 
Could not load conf for core testcore: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml]
fieldType "nametext": Cannot load analyzer:
org.apache.lucene.analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer. Schema file is E:\files\future\solr-5.0.0\server\solr\testcore\conf\schema.xml
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In Solr 5.0.0 this class is in the `org.apache.lucene.analysis.core` package, so the class should be `org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.WhitespaceAnalyzer` - see documentation: http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/analyzers-common/index.html